# How can I have a referenced function keep its parent scope?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a workaround for the following situation :

```
obj1 = {
 number : 1,
 mynumber : function(){
   console.log(this.number);
 }
}

foo = obj1.mynumber

foo(); //undefined
```

Simplifying, how can I make `foo()` print `number`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Through the magic of [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)!

`bind` allows you to create a copy of a function with the `this` value (along with any number of parameters) explicitly set to whatever you want.

```js
obj1 = {
 number : 1,
 mynumber : function(){
   console.log(this.number);
 }
}

foo = obj1.mynumber.bind(obj1); // <--

foo(); // 1
```

Comment: So, in the end `this` is just a variable like any other? In a case that I bind `this` it will overwrite the "natural" `this`of the scope it is in?

Comment: @Mojimi You've got it.